# Other than mocked method call actual methods for a mock object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

```
IFoo
{
    string abc();
    string def();
}

Foo: IFoo
{
    string abc()
    {
        def();
    }

    string def()
    {
    }
}

Mymainclass
{
    private IFoo _foo;

    public Mymainclass():this(new Foo())
    {}

    public Mymainclass(IFoo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    string mainmethod()
    {
        _foo.abc();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class Mymainclasstester
{
    Mymainclass mainclass;
    Mock<IFoo> mifoo;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        mifoo = new Mock<IFoo>();
        mifoo.Setup(x => x.def(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("abc");
        mainclass = new Mymainclass(mifoo.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void testmethod()
    {
        mainclass.mainmethod();
    }
}
```

As seen above in the testmethod() i am calling mainmethod() of class Mymainclass, which inturn calls abc() of Foo class.
abc() makes call to def() as it can be seen in the above code. I have mocked only def().
When the call is made from testmethod() i want to make an actual call to abc() of Foo, and mock only def().

Currently with this implementation abc() is not executing.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You could set up `abc` to invoke `def` but it is really unclear why are you doing it, seems not as the correct way... Something like: `mock.Setup(x => x.abc()).Returns(() => mock.Object.def());`

Comment: Moq doesn't know how you implemented IFoo interface in it's derived class (i.e. Foo) That's why it throws an exception.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot archive what you want using `interface`. Actually, you can but by mocking `abc` to invoke `def` which seems a bit awkward:

```
mock.Setup(x => x.abc()).Returns(() => mock.Object.def());
```

Although I don't see the point here, you could just mock `abc` instead...

---

The only way to archive what you want using mock is by using actual `class` and `Callbase` feature.

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public virtual string abc() //methods have to be virtual to be mockable
    {
        return def();
    }

    public virtual string def() //methods have to be virtual to be mockable
    {
        return "123";
    }
}

//setup
var mock = new Mock<Foo>();
mock.Setup(x => x.def()).Returns("abc");
mock.Setup(x => x.abc()).CallBase();

mock.Object.abc(); // "abc"
```

In this case, you are setting up the actual class instead of the interface so you need to refactor a bit your implementation. Not sure if this is the right approach just the way how to implement your requirement.